# Jquery not appending values even though values do exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to add to a exsiting table structure of jquery using the following

```
        function GetViewData(data) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Services/Configuration/ViewServices.asmx/GetIncidentViewData",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnViewDataLoaded,
                error: OnViewDataNodeLoadFailed
            });
        }

        function OnViewDataLoaded(data, status) {
            $('#viewpane-table > tbody').empty();
            var members = data.d;
            var loadedFirst = false;

            var tablevalues = '';
            $.each(data.d.Columns, function (index, value) {
                tablevalues += FormatValues(value.ColumnValue);
            });


            $('#viewpane-table  > tbody').append(tablevalues);





        }
```

But for some reason its not showing the data below my html table layout is a basic one I am hopeing that someone can help been driving me nuts for 30 mins. Their is no error and the data is being returned i am thinking its something to do with way I am appending the data onto the table?

```
<td><b>test</b></td><td><b>test</b></td><td><b>test</b></td><td><b>test</b></td><td><b>test</b></td><td><b>test</b></td><td><b>test</b></td><td><b>test</b></td><td><b>test</b></td><td><b>test</b></td><td><b>test</b></td><td><b>test</b></td><td><b>test</b></td>
```

The table is just simple html markup

```
<table id="viewpane-table" style="width:100%">
<thead></thead>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Function FormatValuesValues is

```
function FormatValues(value) {
    return '<td><b>' + value + '</b></td>';
}
```

Comment: what is FormatValues() ?

Comment: Get rid of the contentType- that's not the correct way to use it.

Comment: @Ariel its a framework another developer put in place so I was told to stick with it

Comment: @AnoopJoshi I added the function above in last edit thanks

Comment: @AnoopJoshi that is it their after I have done processing it in the  the line showing <td><b>test</b></td> was already their

Comment: You are telling the server you are sending it json, but you are not. It's a mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a row. Now you are trying to append `td` directly to `tbody` whic wolud result in invalid html. Change the code like this

```
function OnViewDataLoaded(data, status) {
    $('#viewpane-table > tbody').empty();
    var members = data.d;
    var loadedFirst = false;

    var tablevalues = '<tr>';
    $.each(data.d.Columns, function (index, value) {
        tablevalues += FormatValues(value.ColumnValue);
    });

    tablevalues += '</tr>';
    $('#viewpane-table  > tbody').append(tablevalues);

}
```

Comment: @abhitalks yes you are correct. Let me edit the answer